# Python mocking: How to test the number of calls on a recursive function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, recursion, mocking

I have a recursive function living in a module called `test_module`

```
import requests    

def send_msg(msg, retries=0):
    try:
        # send the message here, e.g. a http request
        response = requests.get("http://www.doesnotexist98734.com")
        # if url does not exist raise an exception
    except Exception as e:
        if retries == 0:
            raise e
        else:
            return send_msg(msg, retries=retries-1)
```

My question is how can I write a unittest that checks the `send_msg` function is called n times when I set retries = n. I was playing around with the mock module (I'm using python 2.7) and I think I want something a bit like this,

```
import mock, unittest

class MyUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('test_module.send_msg')
    def test_send_msg_tries_n_times(self, mock_send_msg):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            mock_send_msg("hello", retries=3)
        self.assertEqual(mock_send_msg.call_count, 4) # initial call + 3 retries
```

However since I have mocked the function it won't call the real function so I don't get an exception nor does it call itself recursively...

Comment: You shouldn't be testing that it calls itself recursively (which is an implementation detail), just that the behaviour is correct (i.e. that it tries to make the request up to `n` times). What if you later decide to refactor to an iterative implementation?

Comment: Generally, if you are testing method `foo`, you do not want to mock out method `foo` as a part of your test. If you do, you are not testing your method, but the mock.

Comment: Testing the behaviour is what I want to do here, how do I check the request is made `n` times?

Comment: See Martjin's answer below. It is precisely what you should do instead (mock something internal to the method, not the method itself).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't mock the function under test. You want to test for *expected results*, not if the function used recursion correctly.

Mock the `request.get()` call, and have it always produce an exception. Then count how often your mock was called.

```
@mock.patch('requests.get')
def test_send_msg_tries_n_times(self, req_get_mock):
    req_get_mock.side_effect = Exception
    with self.assertRaises(Exception):
        send_msg("hello", retries=3)
    self.assertEqual(req_get_mock.call_count, 4)  # 1 initial call + 3 retries
```

If in future you want to avoid using recursion and want to use iteration instead, your test still will work as it validates the behaviour, not the specific implementation. You can safely refactor the function-under-test.

Answer (score 4):

I find verifying the recursive call structure of a function to be an incredibly useful feature of a unit test.
This can be accomplished easily by using the `side_effect` argument in `Mock`, instead of using the `patch` decorator.

`side_effect` accepts a function, which will be passed the same arguments as the `Mock`. The the return value of the `Mock` is also the return value of the `side_effect` function. What this means is that we can pass the original function to the `Mock` as a `side_effect`, and effectively have a `Mock` wrapper around our recursive function.

For example:

```
def test_send_msg_tries_n_times(self, mock_send_msg):
    test_module.send_msg = Mock(side_effect=test_module.send_msg)

    test_module.send_msg("hello", retries=3)
    test.module.send_msg.assert_has_calls([
        call("hello", retries=3),
        call("hello", retries=2),
        call("hello", retries=1),
        call("hello", retries=0),
    ])
```