# How to test non-pure (containing side effects) recursive graph traversal function using the Mock library?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a Depth First Search algorithm function to recursively traverse through a DAG (Directed Aclyclic Graph) to find dependencies amongst parent and children nodes, and then finally return a list of those dependencies.

For each dependency within the initial node, I am using a function from another class to assign the next node from the dependency respectively, to be able to "check the next one".

I am using Mock to set up unit tests for this. But I can't seem to make it work since there are side effects within the function I'm testing (ie, another function call for each iteration). Please see example code below:

```
# Simplified version of the DFS algorithm to show necessary information
def recursive_function(other_class, object_to_check, list_to_return=None):
    if list_to_return is None:
        list_to_return = [object_to_check]

    dependencies = object_to_check.dependencies

    if dependencies :
        for dep in dependencies:

            # this is the function call thats making it problematic
            next_object = other_class.get_next_object_from_dep(dep)

            list_to_return.append(next_object)
            recursive_function(other_class, next_object, list_to_return)

    return list_to_return
```

As you can see, I am calling **other_class.get_next_object_from_dep(dep)** from within my traversal function. I have tried setting up unit tests for this, but I can't get it to work.

I know theres Mock, MagicMock, setting up patching, setting up return_value as well as side_effects within Mock if there are any, but I still can't to get these puzzle pieces together.

Example of my current testing, simplified:

```
MOCK_PARENT= '''
{
    "id": 1337
}
'''

MOCK_CHILD= '''
{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": 1337
}
'''

# So testing on MOCK_CHILD should return both MOCK_CHILD 
# and MOCK_PARENT as MOCK_CHILD is dependent on MOCK_PARENT (preceding dependency).

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_parent = MockParentClass(json.loads(MOCK_PARENT))
        self.mock_child = MockChildClass(json.loads(MOCK_CHILD))
        self.parent = ParentClass(self.mock_parent)
        self.child = ChildClass(self.mock_child)

        self.m = Mock()
        self.session = Session()
        self.other_class = OtherClass(self.session)

    # Do I need to add a @mock.patch decorator here?
    def test_graph_traversal(self):
        expected_results = [ChildObject, ParentObject]

        # matches --> "def recursive_function(other_class, object_to_check, list_to_return=None)"
        objects_from_my_func = recursive_function(self.other_class, self.child, [self.child])
        assertEquals(objects_from_my_func, expected_results)
```

Doing this approach, I'm getting errors like **"Mock object has no attribute function ..."** etc.

**In essence, how should I think around testing a recursive function that also has side effects?** I can't work around the side effects as I need that outer function call within my traversal to find the next node to check. I'm fairly new to the whole unit testing so using Mock library is something I really want to learn.

Comment: Maybe the two answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993268/python-mocking-how-to-test-the-number-of-calls-on-a-recursive-function) are helpful.

Comment: I think you have to define DAG's that trigger all the wanted execution paths, and then test that the observable behaviour for each DAG case is the correct one.

Comment: That is, that the mocks you place are called as they should. Note that you can have mocks that call the real methods, using `wraps`, and still have their calls spied. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610170/python-unittest-patch-mock-entier-class/64744008#64744008)

Comment: @progmatico Thanks for the replies.

For my use case though; my function returns a list of "nodes" (class objects) that we are using in other functions, so I really need to test if my function returns the correct "nodes" based on the condition if they are dependent on one another... 

Is it therefore still valid to **only test the call count**, as one respond suggested, and not if the correct objects was returned from my function? I basically wanna do exactly what my function does but have all of it mocked into fake objects/nodes so they dont actually gets created and iterated through.

Comment: No, that was because call count in that case was the essential part of the problem (making sure there were n retries upon n-1 send failures). As I said setup short DAG structures that you know will trigger all the code paths of your algorithm, You can mock  `other_class.get_next_object_from_dep()` to return the values from a known sequence too.

Comment: You can also check that the calls happened as they should, in the right order and args besides having a check for the right result.